# Check multiple list sizes in JSTL

Tags: spring, jstl, jstl-functions

How do I chain multple length checks?

I tried these ways to no effect:

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(app.applicationAdminComments) le 0  or fn:length(app.applicationChoComments) le 0  }">
```

and

```
<c:if test="${(fn:length(app.applicationAdminComments) le 0)  || (fn:length(app.applicationChoComments) le 0 )}">
```

but neither is working.

Comment: Do you add: `<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>`?

Comment: Have it added :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't get an error, the possible causes are:

- app.applicationAdminComments is null
- app.applicationChoComments is null
- length of app.applicationAdminComments is 0
- length of app.applicationChoComments is 0